# Is it possible to add &:after to the parent in SASS?

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to clean up some SCSS-Code I wrote previously, back then I didn't really care about redudant code so I wrote stuff like this:

```
.example {
  .child {
    .grandchild {
      //CSS CODE
    }
  }
  &:nth-child(odd) {
    .child {
      .grandchild {
        //CSS CODE
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I'm refactoring some code and im trying to do something like this:

```
.example {
  .child {
    .grandchild {
      //CSS CODE
      &:nth-child(odd) & {
        //CSS CODE
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which compiles into something like this:

```
.example .child .grandchild:nth-child(odd) .example .child .grandchild
```

But what I want is this:

```
.example:nth-child(odd) .child .grandchild
```

Is this possible with SCSS or should I stick with my previous code?

Comment: Is `@at-root` perhaps what you are looking for? https://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#at-root_without__and_at-root_with_

Comment: I've seen this one as well but wouldn't this be the same result as before that I had to write every child class separately again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inserting a new modifier *in the middle* of a rule isn't really a feature of Sass. Generally, you can only add things to the beginning or the end. Additionally, the [@at-root](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#at-root_without__and_at-root_with_) directive allows you to "reset" the current context.

As such, you always have to organize you code so that the pieces are "chunked" to allow for the inserting at the beginning or the end.

So something like this might work:

```
.example {
  color: yellow;

  @at-root {
    .child {
      .grandchild {
        .example & {
          color: red;
        }

        .example:nth-child(odd) & {
          color: blue;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Compiles to:

```
.example {
  color: yellow;
}
.example .child .grandchild {
  color: red;
}
.example:nth-child(odd) .child .grandchild {
  color: blue;
}
```